# How connect my exist gradle with react native project?

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

When I download gradle file from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip),  where should I put this zip file?

I tried to put in .gradle folder and then type `react-native run-android` again  todownload gradle file from above website but I already downloaded it.

Where should I put this downloaded gradle zip file so again react-native not downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

first run `react-native run-android` after starting download file from website then stop this download and going .gradle folder which in into home page (in ubunut) after going to wrapper/dists then you show gradel-x.x.x-all. click on this folder and show one folder which name like random alphabet name . then put zip file in this folder and extracct file . after extracting file dispaly 1 file ,1 zip folder and 1 folder extract folder . 
then go back in your project and run again `react-native run-android` and it's work